# Python Pandas operate on row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi my dataframe look like:

```
Store,Dept,Date,Sales
1,1,2010-02-05,245
1,1,2010-02-12,449
1,1,2010-02-19,455
1,1,2010-02-26,154
1,1,2010-03-05,29
1,1,2010-03-12,239
1,1,2010-03-19,264
```

Simply, I need to add another column called '_id' as concatenation of Store, Dept, Date like "1_1_2010-02-05", I assume I can do it through df['*id'] = df['Store'] +'*' +df['Dept'] +'_'+df['Date'], but it turned out to be not.

Similarly, i also need to add a new column as log of sales, I tried df['logSales'] = math.log(df['Sales']), again, it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first convert it to strings (the integer columns) before concatenating with `+`:

```
In [25]: df['id'] = df['Store'].astype(str) +'_' +df['Dept'].astype(str) +'_'+df['Date']

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
   Store  Dept        Date  Sales              id
0      1     1  2010-02-05    245  1_1_2010-02-05
1      1     1  2010-02-12    449  1_1_2010-02-12
2      1     1  2010-02-19    455  1_1_2010-02-19
3      1     1  2010-02-26    154  1_1_2010-02-26
4      1     1  2010-03-05     29  1_1_2010-03-05
5      1     1  2010-03-12    239  1_1_2010-03-12
6      1     1  2010-03-19    264  1_1_2010-03-19
```

For the `log`, you better use the `numpy` function. This is vectorized (`math.log` can only work on single scalar values):

```
In [34]: df['logSales'] = np.log(df['Sales'])

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
   Store  Dept        Date  Sales              id  logSales
0      1     1  2010-02-05    245  1_1_2010-02-05  5.501258
1      1     1  2010-02-12    449  1_1_2010-02-12  6.107023
2      1     1  2010-02-19    455  1_1_2010-02-19  6.120297
3      1     1  2010-02-26    154  1_1_2010-02-26  5.036953
4      1     1  2010-03-05     29  1_1_2010-03-05  3.367296
5      1     1  2010-03-12    239  1_1_2010-03-12  5.476464
6      1     1  2010-03-19    264  1_1_2010-03-19  5.575949
```

Summarizing the comments, for a dataframe of this size, using `apply` will not differ much in performance compared to using vectorized functions (working on the full column), but when your real dataframe becomes larger, it will.
Apart from that, I think the above solution is also easier syntax.

Comment: I get 164us using math vs 151us using numpy log, I'm assuming that for a large dataframe numpy's one will eat Math's log for breakfast?

Comment: Indeed, I get 201us (np) vs 208us (math), so almost the same for this dataframe, but for a larger one (this one 100 times repeated), numpy is clearly faster than using apply.

Comment: For a dataframe with 7000 rows math.log takes 2.17ms versus np.log time of 240us so a significant performance improvement

Comment: Also for the concatenation, for this dataframe, using apply is not slower (even a bit faster 500 vs 700 us), but for larger dataframes (7000 rows) it is again clearly slower (200 vs 80 ms).

Comment: yes I would expect this too, good to know that the vectorised operations scale well, I still have more to learn about pandas and numpy ;)

Comment: Regarding to the performance, I just notice if I use the vectorized functions, I may cause a memoryError (I have 3G ram) but apply does not have such a problem. So I think the vectorized functions are reading everything in memory right? The original file is about 12M in size, above is just a sample section of the file

Comment: BTW, I tried the same operation with R in the same computer, and R can handle the file very fast

Comment: If the file is only 12 Mb, you should not encounter MemoryErrors with the above code. If that is the case, there is clearly something wrong.

Comment: @joris yeah, you are right, it is not due to insufficient RAM bcuz I tested it on a 8G ram machine as well. Instead, the problem seems to be cause by this statement: df['Store'].astype(str) +'_'+ df['Dept'].astype(str). It works file with a samll file with a few rows, but it crashed when rows are more than 100K. 
It is that line that causes the MemoryError.

Comment: I am not sure if I am using something wrongly, but even I do a simple mutiplication like: df['storedept'] = df['Store'].astype(int) * df['Dept'].astype(int), it causes a memoryError, could you tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: I tried df['Store'].astype(str) with 700K rows, and it runs without any problems as expected (on a machine with 4G ram). Can you show `df.info()`, `pd.show_versions()`, your system specs and the full error message (or maybe better open a new question for it)

Comment: Thanks, I open a new question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956390/python-pandas-memoryerror

Answer (score 2):

```
In [153]:
import pandas as pd
import io

temp = """Store,Dept,Date,Sales
1,1,2010-02-05,245
1,1,2010-02-12,449
1,1,2010-02-19,455
1,1,2010-02-26,154
1,1,2010-03-05,29
1,1,2010-03-12,239
1,1,2010-03-19,264"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
df
Out[153]:
   Store  Dept        Date  Sales
0      1     1  2010-02-05    245
1      1     1  2010-02-12    449
2      1     1  2010-02-19    455
3      1     1  2010-02-26    154
4      1     1  2010-03-05     29
5      1     1  2010-03-12    239
6      1     1  2010-03-19    264

[7 rows x 4 columns]
In [154]:
# apply a lambda function row-wise, you need to convert store and dept to strings in order to build the new string
df['id'] = df.apply(lambda x:  str(str(x['Store']) + ' ' + str(x['Dept']) +'_'+x['Date']), axis=1)
df
Out[154]:
   Store  Dept        Date  Sales              id
0      1     1  2010-02-05    245  1 1_2010-02-05
1      1     1  2010-02-12    449  1 1_2010-02-12
2      1     1  2010-02-19    455  1 1_2010-02-19
3      1     1  2010-02-26    154  1 1_2010-02-26
4      1     1  2010-03-05     29  1 1_2010-03-05
5      1     1  2010-03-12    239  1 1_2010-03-12
6      1     1  2010-03-19    264  1 1_2010-03-19

[7 rows x 5 columns]
In [155]:

import math
# now apply log to sales to create the new column
df['logSales'] = df['Sales'].apply(math.log)
df
Out[155]:
   Store  Dept        Date  Sales              id  logSales
0      1     1  2010-02-05    245  1 1_2010-02-05  5.501258
1      1     1  2010-02-12    449  1 1_2010-02-12  6.107023
2      1     1  2010-02-19    455  1 1_2010-02-19  6.120297
3      1     1  2010-02-26    154  1 1_2010-02-26  5.036953
4      1     1  2010-03-05     29  1 1_2010-03-05  3.367296
5      1     1  2010-03-12    239  1 1_2010-03-12  5.476464
6      1     1  2010-03-19    264  1 1_2010-03-19  5.575949

[7 rows x 6 columns]
```